# ADB loses connection to emulated device on Genymotion when Device is plugged in via USB

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, genymotion

I'm using Windows 8.1 with Android Studio 0.8.14. As an emulator i use Genymotion 2.3.0. This works all fine for me so far. I'm able to start a VD from AndroidStudio and launch an App on it.

Now when i plug in my phone (HTC one m7) ADB loses connection to the emulator. Also my phone is not recognized by ADB.